# How to fetch collection from firebase cloud firestore into a ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-viewpager

friends I just implement code for the View pager. But now I am stuck with the problem that how to fetch a collection from the firestore into a view pager. Means I have a collection in that collection I have 2 documents. each document has some parameters. I want the "mSliderImage" parameter will be fetched into a ViewPager from each and every document.

My Code Some How Looks Like This.

I am using some dependencies for my custom viewpager.

```
implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.3.2'      
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'             
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
```

image_slider_myshop.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_auto_image_slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_gif_container"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_margin="50dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_shadow_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_overlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_auto_image_slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

main_image_slider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mpm_slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10sp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView
        android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:sliderAnimationDuration="600"
        app:sliderAutoCycleEnabled="true"
        app:sliderCircularHandlerEnabled="true"
        app:sliderIndicatorAnimationDuration="600"
        app:sliderIndicatorGravity="right|bottom"
        app:sliderIndicatorMargin="15dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorOrientation="horizontal"
        app:sliderIndicatorPadding="3dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorRadius="2dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorSelectedColor="#5A5A5A"
        app:sliderIndicatorUnselectedColor="#FFF"
        app:sliderScrollTimeInSec="7"
        app:sliderStartAutoCycle="true" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

home_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/main_header"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Java Codes:

Adapter Code: "The Images which get fetched in below switch cases code are an image which directly comes from google. Instead of this, I want image will get fetched from firebase firestore "Banner" collection for each document having "mSliderImage" parameter"

```
public class SliderImageAdapter extends SliderViewAdapter<SliderImageAdapter.SliderAdapterVH> {

private Context context;
private int mCount;

public SliderImageAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.mCount = count;
}

@Override
public SliderAdapterVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    View inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_slider_myshop, null);
    return new SliderAdapterVH(inflate);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SliderAdapterVH viewHolder, final int position) {

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                    .load("https://laz-img-cdn.alicdn.com/images/ims-web/TB1pHADjBr0gK0jSZFnXXbRRXXa.jpg_1200x1200.jpg")
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);
            break;
        case 1:
            Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                    .load(" switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                    .load(" switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                    .load("https://www.arihantwebtech.com/images/design-notice/banner-design.png")
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);
            break;
        case 1:
            Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                    .load("https://www.arihantwebtech.com/images/design-notice/banner-design.png")
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);
            break;")
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);
            break;
        case 1:
            Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                    .load("https://www.arihantwebtech.com/images/design-notice/banner-design.png")
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);
            break;")
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);
            break;

    }
}

public int getCount() {
    //slider view count could be dynamic size
    return mCount;
}

class SliderAdapterVH extends SliderViewAdapter.ViewHolder {

    View itemView;
    ImageView imageViewBackground;
    ImageView imageGifContainer;
    TextView textViewDescription;

    public SliderAdapterVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageViewBackground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_auto_image_slider);
        imageGifContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_gif_container);
        textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_auto_image_slider);
        this.itemView = itemView;
    }
}
}
```

Home Fragment Code:

```
SliderView sliderMyshop;
 public static Fragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        }
    }

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

        sliderMyshop = view.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);

final SliderImageAdapter sliderImageAdapter = new SliderImageAdapter(getContext());
        sliderImageAdapter.setCount(4);
        sliderMyshop.setSliderAdapter(sliderImageAdapter);
        sliderMyshop.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimations.WORM); //set indicator animation by using SliderLayout.IndicatorAnimations. :WORM or THIN_WORM or COLOR or DROP or FILL or NONE or SCALE or SCALE_DOWN or SLIDE and SWAP!!
        sliderMyshop.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.SIMPLETRANSFORMATION);
        sliderMyshop.setIndicatorSelectedColor(Color.WHITE);
        sliderMyshop.setIndicatorUnselectedColor(Color.GRAY);
        sliderMyshop.startAutoCycle();
        sliderMyshop.setOnIndicatorClickListener(new DrawController.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIndicatorClicked(int position) {
                sliderMyshop.setCurrentPagePosition(position);
            }
        });
```

I am also attaching the pic of the [image: firebase firestore. Collection - Document - SliderImage]